# Pass GridView Cell Value to Sub Routine in ASP.NET / VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView with Cell 0 containing the ID that I need to pass to a Public Sub.

I cannot figure out how to pick the value from Cell 0 in order to pass it to the Sub. I have tried experimenting (see the Dimmed EventID below) but have failed. Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub gvAppointmentsCalls_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvAppointmentsCalls.RowCommand

        Dim EventID As String = gvAppointmentsCalls.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text

        If e.CommandName = "gvAdd2Outlook" Then
            Send_iCal_Call(EventID)
        End If
    End Sub
```

If I type the value directly e.g. `Send_iCal_Call(123)` then it works perfectly.

```
Public Sub Send_iCal_Call(ByRef Event_ID As Integer)
' My code in here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.commandargument.aspx) to pass the ID to the RowCommand-Handler.

For example:

```
CommandName="gvAdd2Outlook" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("EventID")%>'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should obtain your ID value within GridView's DataKeyNames property. You should define it in your grid markup this property like here

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="EvenID">
```

and then will access it in code behind:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

   If e.CommandName = "gvAdd2Outlook" Then
        Dim EventIDString As String = GridView1.DataKeys.Item(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
        Dim EventID As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(EventIDString, EventID) = False Then Throw New ArgumentException("Wrong EventID=" & EventID)

        Send_iCal_Call(EventID)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great answer and I wasn't aware you could do what you have stated, however the answer from Tim was exactly what I needed. Thanks